# How do I run a Python script on my web server?

Tags: python, webserver, cgi-bin

I've just started learning Python, and I'm pretty lost right now. I want to run my script on my server that is hosted through hosting24.com. Their FAQ says they support Python, but I have no clue where to put my script for it to run.

There is a folder called cgi-bin in my root, I'm guessing that is where I put my script? Can someone explain to me how this works?

Comment: I don't see how this is off topic.

Comment: Nor do I. Carlos' short and precise answer is the proof for that question not being "too broad".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Very simply, you can rename your Python script to "pythonscript.cgi".
Post that in your cgi-bin directory, add the appropriate permissions and browse to it.

[This is a great link](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/webservers.html) you can start with.

[Here's another good one.](https://autofei.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/add-python-support-to-apache2-in-ubuntu-using-mod_python/)

Hope that helps.

---

**EDIT (09/12/2015):** The second link has long been removed.  Replaced it with one that provides information referenced from the original.

Comment: I placed a file called test.cgi in the cgi-bin, gave it 777 perms, navigated to it, but I get a 500 internal service error.

Comment: Can you post what your, I'm assuming, Apache error.log states?

Comment: Here's a [great writeup](http://encodable.com/internal_server_error/) of what would constitute a 500 error

Comment: [Wed Feb 22 11:16:28 2012] [error] [client 204.xx.xx.70] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/home/xxxxx/public_html/cgi-bin/test.py' failed

Comment: Though I gave it 777 Perms (or so I thought).

Comment: See [this aricle](http://www.slingcode.com/suexec.php) regarding user directories and suexec.

Comment: It turned out that my FTP client wasn't setting the permissions even though it said it did.

Comment: Cool answer @Carlos, but the second link is now broken. Is there a fresh link I was really interested to read it. Cheers

Comment: Thanks @JasTonAChair.  Even though the original link is dead, I put up one that references data from the original.