# How to upload new python(django) project to server?

Tags: python, django, server

I have uploaded my django files into the server...
When I worked on local host I wrote in console `python manage.py runserver`

How do I tell the server that He should run this project?

I read this topic [How do I run a Python script on my web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398560/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-on-my-web-server) but it doesn't proved actuall instructions. I have no idea what is this cgi folder. The documntation link there isn't much of help as well.

My server runs many applications and it's already on... I wish to add a new python application to it.

Comment: There are perfectly good instructions on deployment in the Django docs. Did you read them?

Answer (score 3):

Django's `runserver` is not supposed to work for production server, you will need to use [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) or [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for this and of course disabling DEBUG mode with `DEBUG=False`

You can use this [tutorial](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/) which help you how to setup your server and use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to manage processes.

Comment: The guide is setting up a new server.... My server is already up, the projects already sits there. I just need the equivelent of runserver.... DEBUG settings are off.

Comment: you do not _need_ gunicorn nor uwsgi, actually you can use any server setup that meets your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always log into the server and use the same commands.

But as Mounir says, the development server isn't intended for production use. Instead you should run it using a "proper" web server. I personally have exeprience using Apache to do this, though there are oher options. A lot really depends on the server setup. Does it have Apache (or Nginx or something similar)?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/