# How to run python script from web page?

Tags: php, python, web-development-server

Im quite new in web developing, could someone please point me in the right direction of help with the scripts to run a .py script on a web page. Below are the ones that i am using. Do i have to create a html file and a php file??
If so please help me. I have a internal server running on XAMPP with Apache and configured to run CGI, .py scripts.

Work flow:

Upload > button to run the below .py script > download

Upload script(php):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['UploadButton'])){ //check if form was submitted

$target_dir = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/pic-el/Dump/';
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["filepath"]["name"]);
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filepath"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
} 
?>
```

Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import CGIHTTPServer
CGIHTTPServer.test()
import os
import urllib
import cgi
import webcolors 
import xlsxwriter
from PIL import Image

filename = "/home/Desktop/tess/test1"

imageNameArray = []


def downloadfile(urlData):
    urllib.urlretrieve(urlData[0], urlData[1])
    print " image downloaded: " + str(urlData[1])
    return


# open file to read
with open("{0}.csv".format(filename), 'r') as csvfile:
    # iterate on all lines
    i = 0
    for line in csvfile:
        splitted_line = line.split(',')
        # check if we have an image URL
        if splitted_line[1] != '' and splitted_line[1] != "\n":
            # urllib.urlretrieve(splitted_line[1], '/home/tf_files/images/{0}.jpg'.format (splitted_line[0]))
            imageNameArray.append(
                (splitted_line[1], '/home/Desktop/tess/images/{0}.jpg'.format(splitted_line[0])))
            print "Image added to list for processing for {0}".format(splitted_line[0])
            i += 1
        else:
            print "No result for {0}".format(splitted_line[0])

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

from multiprocessing import Pool

processPool = Pool(5)
processPool.map(downloadfile, imageNameArray)

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output1.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0

# search for files in 'images' dir
files_dir = os.getcwd() + '/images'
files = os.listdir(files_dir)


def closest_colour(requested_colour):
    min_colours = {}
    for key, name in webcolors.css3_hex_to_names.items():
        r_c, g_c, b_c = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key)
        rd = (r_c - requested_colour[0]) ** 2
        gd = (g_c - requested_colour[1]) ** 2
        bd = (b_c - requested_colour[2]) ** 2
        min_colours[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
    return min_colours[min(min_colours.keys())]


def get_colour_name(requested_colour):
    try:
        closest_name = actual_name = webcolors.rgb_to_name(requested_colour)
    except ValueError:
        closest_name = closest_colour(requested_colour)
        actual_name = None
    return actual_name, closest_name


for f in files:
    if f.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg')):
        image_path = files_dir + '/' + f
        im = Image.open(image_path)
        n, cl = max(im.getcolors(im.size[0] * im.size[1]))
        requested_colour = cl
        actual_name, closest_name = get_colour_name(requested_colour)


        width = im.size
        if width < (500, 500):
            worksheet.write(row, 4, "False")
        else:
            worksheet.write(row, 4, "True")

        print image_path
        print cl
        print width
        print "Actual colour name:", actual_name, ", closest colour name:", closest_name


        worksheet.write_string(row, 1, image_path)
        worksheet.write(row, 3, closest_name)   
        row += 1





workbook.close()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398560/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-on-my-web-server

Comment: You could also have a look at the https://www.djangoproject.com and use Django as your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

you can't run .py on a web page, only u can run on the server since Python's a server side programming. But you can run python script from PHP (since u r using XAMPP.)
Example -

```
<?php
   $output =  exec('./filename.py');
?>
```

Comment: Nothing seems to work when i tried the above. How display error on the page?

Comment: just echo out the $output. When u run exec('./filename.py'), it'll return the output from python.
check it.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant output - assumed 'output' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/IMG/ne.php on line 3
output    -  Thats what is being displayed. Unable to understand what it means

Comment: <?php
           $output =  exec('./tet.py');
           echo output
?>

Comment: it's echo $output, not echo output.

Comment: tried that.. nothing seems to happen.. just got a blank page

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create separate php and html files.

First, when the server goes back to apache2

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi`

(It connects apache2 with wsgi.)

Second, you need to create a configuration file and

Move the configuration file to Document_Root.

```
ex> server.conf

WSGIScriptAlias /test /var/www/wsgi/main.py
```

MainOption |  Address to be connected | Python file location

Third, restart apache2 service.

**EXAMPLE_CODES**

[main.py](https://gist.github.com/keyakoto/6a3e3c4448f970f84c165bdb0eea0289)

[server.conf](https://gist.github.com/keyakoto/c521f8312652f06e81ada1973577b3b9)

Comment: im on ubuntu, is document_root a folder in apache htdoc folder?

Comment: Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
End of script output before headers: main.py
Above is the error that i got ..

Comment: Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
End of script output before headers: main.py

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 500
172.27.181.60
Apache/2.4.26 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.7 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3